# How to iteratively build and export multiple graphs from 1 data set based on a factor

Tags: r, iteration, graphing

Say I have a data file (WQ_data_forMultipleStations.csv) with three variables: `StationName`, `Time_hr`, and `DO_mgL`.  This file includes data for 50 stations (station1, station2, station3... station50).

I would like to create and export 50 separate graphs, one graph per station, each graph exported as a separate image file.

Each graph would have the same format: `Time_hr` on the x-axis, `DO_mgL` on the y-axis, `StationName` as the graph title, and exported in JPG format with the file name `StationName`.jpg.

I'm new to R, and I've figured out to make one giant plot with 50 subplots using facets (see code below), but I would very much appreciate help making each subplot a separate graph and then exporting the 50 graphs as 50 separate and clearly-named image files.  Thanks!

```
library ("ggplot2")
WQ_byStation <- read.csv("WQ_data_forMultipleStations.csv")
WQ_byStation_plots <- ggplot(WQ_byStation, aes(x = Time_hr, y = DO_mgL)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ StationName)
ggsave(filename="WQ_byStation_plots.jpg", plot=WQ_byStation_plots)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example of how it could be done using for loops with the `mtcars` dataset

```
for(g in unique(mtcars$gear)) {
  f <- filter(mtcars, gear == g)
  
  p <- ggplot(f, aes(disp, hp)) +
    geom_point()
  
  ggsave(paste0('plot_', g,'.jpg'), p)
}
```

In your case it would something like this

```
for(s in unique(WQ_byStation$StationName)){
  
  f <- filter(WQ_byStation, StationName == s)
  
  p <- ggplot(f, aes(x = Time_hr, y = DO_mgL)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(s)
  
  ggsave(paste0(s,'.jpg'), p)
  
}
```

Note you can save to a folder by specifying the path in `ggsave`. E.g. `my_folder/WQ_bySation...`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was able to cleanly run your solution using both the mtcars dataset and my simplified dataset after loading the "dplyr" library.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying! If you didn't want to load `dplyr` you could use `subset` instead of `filter`.